# Microsoft-Cognitive Translator text API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the translator text API, in the process of use, long text translation will be wrong, The following prompt will appear: internal server  error. How can I solve this problem？

Answer (score 0):

We need more information from you:

1. Can you tell us the error code returned with the error message?
2. What version of the Translator Text API are you using? Look at the endpoint. You're using version 3 if you're using the api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com endpoint. Version 2 endpoint is api.microsofttranslator.com and is deprecated. More details is in the article, [API version compatibility and customization](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1854943-api-version-compatibility-and-customization), in the Cognitive Services UserVoice forum.
3. What is the language pair, the source language and the target language?

Comment: 1. ["reasonPhrase":protected]=>

Comment: 1. ["reasonPhrase": protected ]=>
string (21) Internal Server Error" 
[“statusCode”: protected ]=>
int(500)
I can't upload screenshots, and I don't know if this is what you want.
2. I’m using version 2
3. The source language is English, and the target language are Spanish, Russian, Italian,etc. There will be multiple language versions

Comment: Can you post the code you use to call the Microsoft Translator service? For reference, please see the Microsoft Translator Text API v2 to v3 Migration documentation at http://aka.ms/Translatorv3Migration

Comment: I don't know which code is what you want,  can you leave a mail address? I will send the corresponding code to your mailbox. thx

Comment: Please use the Contact Us form to reach the Microsoft Translator team at www.aka.ms/TranslatorContact